# Positive cone of operators: if two selfadjoints $a$, $b$ obey $a^2 + b^2 =1$, must they commute?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, linear-algebra

The question relates to the structure of the positive cone of operators, in C*-algebra.

1. If $a$ and $b$ are selfadjoints such that  $a^2 + b^2 = 1$ can one prove $a$ and $b$ commute? What one derives is $ ba = ba^3 + b^3a $ and $ ab = a^3b + ab^3 $ but I am stuck here, only higher powers seem to commute.
2. Also, if for selfadjoints $a$ and $e$, $a^2 + e^2 = e$, can one prove that $e$ is actually a square of a selfadjoint?
3. Finally, is $1-e$ actually a square of a selfadjoint?

We know that $e$ is the square of a selfadjoint so that, by the textbooks, it is positive but I do not find a complete algebraic proof of this fact: a sum of squares is a square.

Comment: It seems like this would be easy enough to work out in the space of 2x2 matrices.

Comment: The answers to $2$ and $3$ are straightforward. If $e$ is self-adjoint, then for any polynomial $f$, $f(e)$ is self-adjoint. So $e^2$ and $(1-e)^2$ are self-adjoint. For $1$, take $a= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \sigma_x$ and $b= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \sigma_y$ for a counter-example

Answer (score 2):

OP wrote (v2):

> *1) If $a$ and $b$ are selfadjoints such that  $a^2 + b^2 = 1$ can one prove that $a$ and $b$ commute?*

No, it is easy to give two-dimensional counterexamples, e.g.

$$ a~=~\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1 \end{bmatrix}\quad\text{and}\quad b~=~\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix}.$$

Or even simpler: Take $a$ and $b$ to be $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ times any two of the three Pauli matrices, as Trimok suggests in a comment.

> *2) Also, if for selfadjoints $a$ and $e$, $a^2 + e^2 = e$, can one prove that $e$ is actually a square of a selfadjoint?*

Yes, the LHS is a semipositive element, so the RHS $e$ is a semipositive element. Here we are using various characterizations of [semipositive elements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_element):

$$a \text{ semipositive element} $$ 
$$\Updownarrow$$
$$ a \text{ selfadjoint with non-negative eigenvalues}$$
$$\Updownarrow$$ 
$$\exists b: a=b^{\dagger}b$$ 
$$\Updownarrow$$ 
$$\exists b\text{ selfadjoint}: a=b^2$$

> *3) And is $1-e$ actually a square of a selfadjoint?*

Yes, rewrite the equation as $a^2 = e-e^2$. The LHS is a semipositive element, so the RHS $e-e^2$ is also a semipositive element. Hence the eigenvalues $\lambda$ of $e$ must obey $\lambda-\lambda^2\geq 0$. In other words, $0\leq \lambda\leq 1$. Hence $1-e$ is a semipositive element as well.